# pyspark 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'pivot'

Tags: pivot, pyspark

I'm using pyspark 2.0
I have a df like this:

```
    +----------+----------+--------
    |pid       |      date| p_category
    +----------+----------+--------
    |    1ba   |2016-09-30|flat
    |    3ed   |2016-09-30|ultra_thin
    +----------+----------+----------
```

I did a

```
    df.groupBy("p_category","date") \                        
    .agg(countDistinct("pid").alias('cnt'))
```

and I got this:

```
    +-------------+----------+------+
    |p_category   |      date|   cnt|
    +-------------+----------+------+
    |    flat     |2016-09-30|116251|
    |ultra_thin   |2016-09-30|113017|
    +-------------+----------+------+
```

But I want I pivot table like this:

```
    +----------+----------+------+
    |date      |      flat|  ultra-thin
    +----------+----------+------+
   2016-09-30  |    116251|113017
    ------------------------------
   df.groupBy("p_category","date") \                        
    .agg(countDistinct("pid").alias('cnt')).pivot("p_category")
```

I got this error:

'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'pivot'

How could I do a pivot  in such case or is there other solution?
Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You should call `pivot` on [gruped data](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.GroupedData.pivot.html), so first you need to group by `date` and then pivot by `p_category`:

```
>>> df.groupBy('date').pivot('p_category').agg(countDistinct('pid').alias('cnt')).show()
+----------+----+----------+                                                    
|      date|flat|ultra_thin|
+----------+----+----------+
|2016-09-30|   1|         1|
+----------+----+----------+
```

Comment: Looks like a link is outdated but it can still be found on https://spark.apache.org/docs/